# how to open a chrome windows in private mode with awesome wm?

Tags: linux, lua, awesome-wm

I have the code below to open Chrome in normal mode but I would like to have a shortcut for private mode as well.

`awful.key({ modkey,           }, "b", function () awful.spawn.with_shell("google-chrome") end,`
`{description = "open chrome", group = "launcher"}),`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `-incognito`:

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "b", function () awful.spawn.with_shell("google-chrome -incognito") end, {description = "open chrome", group = "launcher"}),
```